# handle login with 2 conditions on history.push only 2nd condition works in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

when i click login with admin user (first condition on handlelogin) the route always takes me to `history.push("/")` not to admin dashboard `"/admin/home"` while it suppose to take me to `"/admin/home"`.
I tried everything but the problem stays the same. with `history.push()`
the handle login works fine only when i login as admin it doesn't want to display url `"/admin/home"`

**Signin.js**

```
const Signin = () => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
   ...
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const [login, setlogin] = useState({
    email:"",
    password:"",
  });

  //const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.user)

  const isAuth = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const isAdmin = localStorage.getItem("isAuth");
  const handleLogin=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(loginUser(login));
    if(isAuth && isAdmin){
      history.push("/admin/home")
    setTimeout(()=>{
      window.location.reload()
    },1000)
    }else{
      history.push("/")
    setTimeout(()=>{
      window.location.reload()
    },1000)
  }
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container component="main" className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Grid item xs={false} sm={4} md={7} className={classes.image} />
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={5} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
          <div className={classes.paper}>
            <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
              <LockOutlinedIcon />
            </Avatar>
            <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
              Connexion
            </Typography>
            <form className={classes.form}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Adresse email"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                autoFocus
                onChange={(e) => setlogin({...login,email:e.target.value})}
              />
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
                required
                fullWidth
                name="password"
                label="Mot de passe"
                type="password"
                id="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                onChange={(e) => setlogin({...login,password:e.target.value})}
              />
              <Button
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.submit}
                onClick={handleLogin}>
                Connexion
              </Button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Signin;
```

**App.js**

```
const  App = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isAuth = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const isAdmin = localStorage.getItem("isAuth");


  useEffect(() => {
    if(isAuth){dispatch(currentUser());
    }
  }, []);
  
let routes = (
  <div>
    <Navbar/>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/connexion"  component={Signin}/>
            <Route path="/inscription" component={SignUp}/>
            </Switch>
            <Footer/>
            </div>
);
if (isAuth && !isAdmin){
  routes=(
    <div>
    <Navbar/>
    <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/message" component={Message}/>
           <Route path="/trajet" component={AddTrajet}/>
            <Route  component={Profile} path="/profile"/>
            <Route component={ListtTrajets} path="/mestrajets"/>
            </Switch>
            <Footer/>
            </div>
  )
}
if (isAuth && isAdmin){
  routes=(<Switch>
   <Route path="/admin/home" component={Admin} />
            </Switch>)
}
  return (
      <div>
          {routes}
      </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Edit**

userSlice.js

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";


export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk("login", async (user) => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/user/login",user);
    return result.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});

const initialState = {
  user: null,
  status: null,
};




export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logout : (state,action)=>{
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      localStorage.removeItem("isAuth");
      state.user = null;
    }
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [loginUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.status = "pending";
    },
    [loginUser.fulfilled]: (state,action) => {
      state.status = "success";
      state.user = action.payload.user;
      localStorage.setItem("token",action.payload.token);
      if(action.payload.user.isAuth){
        localStorage.setItem("isAuth",action.payload.user.isAuth);
      }

    },
    [loginUser.rejected]: (state) => {
      state.status = "fail";
    },

export const {logout} = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your retrieve the value of `isAdmin` and `isAuth` before actually the login occur, there for it will always equal to `false`..
Try modify you code to retrieve those values after the login occur (assuming the `loginUser` function is synchronies:

```js
  const handleLogin=(e)=>{
  
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(loginUser(login));
    
    const isAuth = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const isAdmin = localStorage.getItem("isAuth");
    
    if(isAuth && isAdmin){
    
      history.push("/admin/home")
      setTimeout(()=>{
        window.location.reload()
      },1000)
    
    }else{
    
      history.push("/")
      setTimeout(()=>{
        window.location.reload()
      },1000)
      
    }
  }
```

Comment: i tried that it didn't work

Comment: i added the code of the userSlice so maybe the problem is from that

Comment: sorry, I didn't looked further on your other code files, you need to create `login` function in your reducer, and call it form your async function, also, to use `loginUser` as a async function, which will require the use of `await` or `.then(` before checking the storages values